# Undefined even with null check

Tags: javascript, scope

listener returns undefined, and I believe in start property. This is an observer object.

```
    var updateP = {
        cb: function (event, properties) {
            "listener" in window? listener.next(properties):null
        },
        start: function (listener) {
            dataset.on("update", this.cb)
        },
        stop: function () {
            dataset.off("update", this.cb)
        },
    }
```

Comment: It's difficult to help you with the above question due to the vague description.  Can you provide more details?  Think about it like this:  You are trying to explain something that's clear to you, but others have no idea.  Approach from that perspective.

Comment: `listener` is not defined inside `cb` if that's what you mean. JavaScript uses [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping). The variable `listener` in `start` won't be magically available in `cb`.

Comment: yes that answers it.

Comment: is there a way to write it such that I don't have to repeat myself?

Answer (score 0):

The `listener` variable is local to the `start` function, so you can't access it as a global variable.

Move the definition of `this.cb` inside `updateP.start`, then it will be able to acecss the lexical variable.

```js
var updateP = {
  start: function(listener) {
    function asdf(ab) {
      console.log(ab)
    }
    this.cb = function(event, properties) {
      listener.next(properties)
    };
    dataset.on("update", this.cb)
  },
  stop: function() {
    if (this.cb) {
      dataset.off("update", this.cb);
    }
  },
}
```